# How can identified the font of string which is copied in notepad?

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts, chinese-locale

how to convert Unicode in to Chinese language.please give me any solution.

**Database saving string :**

```
Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

ä¸­å›½åŒ—äº¬å¸‚æœé˜³åŒºæœå¤–å¤§è¡—22å·æ³›åˆ©å¤§åŽ¦408å®¤
```

**Exact Output of the string :**

```
Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

中国北京市朝阳区朝外大街22号泛利大厦408室
```

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing information.issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can open your .java file with a text editor like Notepad++. In the Menu "Encodage", choose "Character Encoding" --> "Chinese". Choose between "Big5" and "GB2312" and save your file.